# Android: How to make a modal custom view?

Tags: android, layout, view

I would like to make my own dialog, completely drawn myself, as a custom view. Can I display it in such a way that it displays above all other views and that all touch events, even those outside the dialog's area, are redirected to the dialog?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I find that using a transparent activity and startActivityForResult() gives me a total freedom how I want my "dialog" to look and behave. So I suggest you check it out: [How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

With full screen and a darker background of your choice:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">     
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparentActivityBackground</item>    
</style>
```

Then in strings.xml:

```
<color name="transparentActivityBackground">#55000000</color>
```

If you want to blur the screen of the previous activity then use this line before setContentView:

```
this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

Comment: Sounds like the most reasonable approach in my situation, thanks! I guess I'll be fine if I just use the built-in Theme.Transluent.

Comment: Also it is important to learn how to make a 9 patch png image which perfectly streaches to make a background for any view, even the text one. Look in C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\ for draw9patch.bat

Comment: FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible by setting the height/width of the root element to anything but `fill_parent`.

You could also achieve this by creating a custom theme that inherits from the built in android dialog theme.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: You mean the dialog's root element? If I don't set it to fill_parent, the user can still interact with the elements beneath, right?

Comment: Upvoted for the suggestion to create a custom dialog theme and use a customized Dialog. You will have a much smoother time doing it that way than trying to put a special view into the hierarchy of an existing window that behaves like a dialog. Dialogs are already there for you to use. :-) The main change you'll want to make in such a custom theme will probably be the windowBackground.

Comment: Yeah I think your right about the background views, I didn't think about that. But as adamp pointed out, using the built in dialogs should help make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my workaround.

First, obtain the decor view's content child view, which is a `FrameLayout`, using `Window#getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)`.

Then, add your custom view to this `FrameLayout` and it will be at the top of other views.